# Calculate correct values to use in layout_weight?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have a design that I want to position the views into these "section" correctly:

[image]

The red areas are empty.
The other "areas" should be centered, the green is ImageView, the other two are TextViews.

To make this possible, someone from this site told me I should use layout_weight.. how can I calculate the correct percentage to use?

What I did was:  Padding on the red sides, and calculated the rest according to the left space.. but the views werent correct.. the xml i tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:paddingTop="10dip"    android:paddingBottom="10dip">

<TextView android:id="@+id/Start_Numbering" android:textSize="19.5dip"
    android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.4" 
    android:gravity="center"
    />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/Start_ImageView"
    android:layout_weight="0.11" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp" android:src="@drawable/quran_list_noaudioavailable"
    android:gravity="center"
    ></ImageView>


<TextView android:id="@+id/Start_Name" android:textColor="#a7e9fe"
    android:textSize="21dip" android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`layout_weight` uses a fraction to determine the size of the children:

> child_space = child_weight / total_weight

where total_weight is the weight sum of all children in the parent layout.

E.g. if you want to have 3 views, two filling 25% of the width and one filling 50%, assign 1 to the first two and 2 to the second. This results in 1/4 (=25%) of the space for each of the two and 2/4  (= 50%) for the third one.

*(you could also use any other number for the first two and double the first weight for the 3rd view, this cancels down to the above fractions)*

You can also just give numbers below 1 as you did above. As long as the total sum is 1 these are interpreted as percentages *(e.g. 0.42 = 42%)*.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning 1 to the value of the padding on the left and make the others multiples of that. (i.e. 1,3,1,5,1)